# SQLite - Clustered Columnstore Index

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlite

Is it possible to create a [clustered columnstore index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-columnstore-index-transact-sql) (from T-SQL) or anything like it on a SQLite3 db table?

I looked at the ['without rowid'](https://sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) argument however it doesn't look like it quite fills the bill.

I've searched google and stackoverflow with no luck as a side note. Thanks!

I'm working on a windows machine w/ Python 3.6, the SQLite3 library and [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) if that matters.

Comment: Why do you want this? The typical use of columnstore indexes in SQL Server is Data Warehousing. Performing aggregate queries on tables with many millions or billions of rows.

Comment: Long story short we're using SQLite as a sub-server of sorts for financial modeling so we're not competing on the main company server (and so we can isolate changes/validations/logs/security/access etc.). We're also doing this on AWS servers as a work around to our companies security policy which slows all writes/bulk inserts to a crawl. As a side effect of that we're doing our best to optimize as non-DBA's.

Comment: SQLite is a "light" database. It was never thought for OLAP. It doesn't have anything remotely similar to a column store. I think you're using a tool too far away from your needs. If you *really* need a column store, you need something like SQL Server, or Oracle, or Teradata, or Vertica.

Comment: Great info joanolo.  We use SQL Server but need something smaller/ more independent for our group which allows quick/easy read/writes via python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite always [stores data in rows](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html).

The only way to emulate something similar would be to split your tables into single-column tables, which probably makes your queries too complex, and would not be much more efficient.